# MouseOver and Mousedown inside a object

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

Hello and sorry my bad english. I create objects with a loop "for" , more or less 200 objects that have inside a Kinetic Image with mouseover and mouseout. The problem is that all the objects are ok, with the image , the problem is that more not works well mouseover and out and I dont know why. No Give me a error in javascript only one warnning with the librarys. If any poeple can check a array of objects that have a imagen with mouse over and out.

```
 CREATE OBJECTS--->

for (var j=0;j<datos.length;j++){ //
    iconos[j]= new icono(images._icono,1, datos[j] ,_conv_lat,_conv_long,factor_conversion_mapa,ConvLat,ConvLong,layer_iconos,stage,j,etiquetas);

FUNCTION --->

function icono(icono_mapa,tipo,datos,_conv_lat,_conv_long,factor_conversion_mapa,ConvLat,ConvLong,layer_icono,stage,i,etiquetas){
    // DEL PIXEL 679 VA EN NEGATIVO ESTE VALOR  (IBIZA-CORUÑA)   //Pixel /Grado
    //this._conv_lat=_conv_lat;
    this.num=i;
    // DEL PIXEL 241 VA EN POSITIVO ESTE VALOR 
    //this._conv_long=_conv_long;
    //this.factor_conversion_mapa= factor_conversion_mapa;
    this.Datos=  new Array();
    this.Datos= datos.slice();
    this.imagen=icono_mapa;
    this.Lat=0;
    this.Long=0;
    this.ConvLat=ConvLat;
    this.ConvLong=ConvLong;
    var _this = this;  
.
.
.
.
.
this.base = new Kinetic.Image({x: _this.Long-( _this.size/2.0), y: _this.Lat -(this.size/2.0)+5, image:_this.imagen, width: _this.size, height: _this.size , name: "icono_"+_this.num});
this.base.on('mouseover', function(evt) {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    etiquetas[_this.num].labelLeft.setAttr('opacity',1);
    layer_etiquetas.draw();
    evt.cancelBubble = true;

});
this.base.on('mouseout', function(evt) {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    etiquetas[_this.num].labelLeft.setAttr('opacity',0);
    layer_icono.draw();
    evt.cancelBubble = true;
});
```

Thank you
if any people could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you.

that things I omited because the code is more large but that is not the problem. Also I find the solution to acelerate the redraw and to work nice in this moment.

Only one Tooltip object, that move to the position AND mouseenter not mouseover

```
var base = new Kinetic.Image({x:Long-( size/2.0), y:Lat -(size/2.0)+5, image:imagen, width:size, height:size , name: "icono_"+num});
base.on('mouseenter mousemove', function(evt) {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        tooltip.setPosition(this.getX()+this.getWidth(), this.getY()+this.getHeight()/2);
        tooltip.setVisible(true);
        tooltip.getText().setText(Datos[4]);
        //tooltip.getText()setText(0,Datos[4]);
        tooltip.moveToTop();
        layer.draw();

  });
base.on('mouseout', function(evt) {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
         tooltip.setVisible(false);
         layer.draw();
  });
```